# WSUS on Win2012R2 doesn't see Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2012, wsus

WSUS on Win2012R2 doesn't see Windows 8.1.

Both machines can ping each other.
Computers are assigned to WSUS by: 'Use Group Policy or registry settings on computers'

Local GPO on Win8.1 is set as follows:

- Configure Automatic Updates is *Enabled*
- Specify intranet Microsoft update service location:

  ```
       Set the intranet updates service for detecting updates: *http://10.13.0.214*
       Set the intranet statistics server: *http://10.13.0.214*
  ```

I have updated the policy, restarted Win 8 but still no joy.

Comment: Are you using port 80 or port 8530 for WSUS?  This one killed me a few times, so I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: Is there anything in the %windir%/WindowsUpdate.log file that would give us more hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by MikeAWood I have added port 8530 to this settings:

Set the intranet updates service for detecting updates: `http://10.13.0.214:8350`

Set the intranet statistics server: `http://10.13.0.214:8350`

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. WSUS v3.0 SP2, server 2008 R2 and Windows 8.1 client devices. WSUS added the devices to the console, but they could not report to the server. I ran a Microsoft fix for it http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734608/ which resolved the issue for me.